# Is it possible to add prefixed values with a command?

Tags: ubuntu, sed, command-line, addition

I have the following list:

```
4. Apples
3. Oranges
2. Lemons
1. Bananas
4. Oranges
3. Lemons
2. Apples
1. Bananas
```

I want it to add the numbers before the fruit and output it as:

```
7. Oranges
6. Apples
5. Lemons
2. Bananas
```

Was wondering if that process is possible using a single line command in the terminal?

Comment: Please show your effort. You would not learn to troubleshoot by simply asking for ready solutions...

Comment: You probably want to use awk, not sed for this.

Comment: My apologizes, Ron. I was able to figure something out with Awk. Here is the code that I used that ended up working: ```awk -F '|' '{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' OFS="|"```

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk`command uses `|`.
I think you simplified your input (thanks!), with this input I can remove the `OFS`, change the ordering and use

```
awk -F '.' '{a[$2] += $1} END {for (i in a) print a[i] "." i}' inputfile
```